# Laravel 8 make POST request to CopyAndPay Api and render form

Tags: laravel, forms, api, controller, laravel-blade

I'm new to laravel and I'm trying to POST form DATA to an [API](https://docs.oppwa.com/tutorials/integration-guide) via a Controller and generate the Copyandpay form to complete the test transaction.

This is what I have so far and I don't know where I'm going wrong.
I keep getting this error
[image]

#### My Controller

```
class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    function request() {
        $url = "https://test.oppwa.com/v1/checkouts";
        $data = "entityId=8a8294174b7ecb28014b9699220015ca" .
                    "&amount=92.00" .
                    "&currency=EUR" .
                    "&paymentType=DB";

         //CURL CONNECTION CODE


    }

}
```

#### My View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://test.oppwa.com/v1/paymentWidgets.js?checkoutId={entityId}"></script>

</head>
<body>
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{ __('Dashboard') }}
        </h2>
        <a href="{{ url('/payment') }}" class="text-sm text-gray-700 underline">Payment</a>
    </x-slot>

    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
                <div class="p-6 bg-white border-b border-gray-200">
                    <form action ="payment" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                        <div class="myDiv">
                            <label for="amount">Amount:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount"><br><br>
                            <label for="reference">Reference:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="reference" name="reference"><br><br>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
                <div class="p-6 bg-white border-b border-gray-200">
                <form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard" class="paymentWidgets" data-brands="VISA MASTER AMEX">
                    @csrf
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
</body>
</html>
```

#### My Route

`Route::post('/payment', [PaymentController::class,'request']);`

Comment: Please let us know what your route is for form submission and also add any Javascript code related to this.

Comment: Added the route code

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this tag from your  tag:

```
<a href="{{ url('/payment') }}" class="text-sm text-gray-700 underline">Payment</a>
```

Your route accepts only post method, but here you are adding it in some sort of navigation item to an anchor tag that corresponds with GET request.

**Note:** You cannot directly go do /payment route by typing in the browser URL bar. You only have to submit your form to this route. In case you can't access the page that contains your payment form, create another route with GET method and connect the route your page in your controller.